# Boostrap input not rounded anymore

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a search box in bootstrap navbar I am doing it like in the example on bootstrap website. I also have an addon in my searchbox. For some reason the inout box is not rounded. This is how it looks now:
[image]

I want the left side to also be rounded like the right side of the addon. 
Below is my code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" id="search" role="search">                                    
                                <button id="search-button" type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                </button>                                   
                                <div id="search-form" class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">                                       
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-input" placeholder="Search">
                                        <span id="search-icon" class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-info">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

I have some additional id's to add dissapearing functionality to the box, much like in [this tutorial](http://forums.asp.net/t/2021642.aspx?Bootstrap+navabar+how+to+hide+and+show+search+textbox).

After adding my CSS I realised that I overridden it I have fixed the CSS and now it is working. Thanx for your help, if you guys didn't suggest to post my CSS I would not have found it.

Comment: Can you show your CSS? As you say the corners should already be rounded so you must be overriding them somewhere in your code.

Comment: As David said, there must be overriding somewhere. Can you implement a demo of your issue?

Comment: As a suggestion, if you could upload your css to a jfiddle and replicate the issue this would be very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this to the class you want to change border radius:
Apply this to your html class in the css file

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: Why implement a work round when the bootstrap CSS is being overridden somewhere?